# Splash screen activity ignored when resuming application - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, onresume

I am wondering why my application ignores my SplashScreen.java activity when resuming the aplication. If I close it with the "Back" button, the splash screen comes up on start, but if I exit with the home button the SplashScreen activity is not being called...:(

I even added the onResume event, but the splash screen still wont come up when resuming my app.
Thanks!!

SplashScreen.java

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        spashStart();

    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        spashStart();
        }   


    private void spashStart() {
        Thread splashTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent mainActivity = new Intent("com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity");
                    startActivity(mainActivity);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                  finish();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTimer.start();
    }

}
```

Maifest:

```
...

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/scena_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > 
        <activity
            android:name="com.exploreca.tourfinder.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </activity>    
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity">            
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".TourDetailActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity">            
        </activity>  
        <activity 
            android:name=".NotificationDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notifDetails_title"
            android:parentActivityName="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity">            
        </activity>  
        <activity 
            android:name=".SavedEvents"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_SavedEvents" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity">            
        </activity>    
        <activity 
            android:name=".FollowList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_Urmarite" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity">            
        </activity>    


...
```

Comment: You want always show splash screen when user starts/come back to your app?

Comment: `if I exit with the home button`, no you don't exit. You put your app in the background.

Comment: Pissing off own users is rather wrong strategy. You should show splash screen only on app launch. Resume, as name indicates, should resume the app in the place user left it.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski - Maybe you right, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you click back button actually the activity is getting finished and when you comes back the splash screen shows. That because once more the appliaction is starting.

When you click home button the activity is not finishing but it goes to background and when you open the app oncemoe then the same activity is bought to front. so the splash screen is not shown.

its how when it works through the lifecycle of the application.

Try to call `finish();` method in th onPause of the activity. So it will be finished all the time. Or try adding `noHistory` to the activity in the manifest. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its not a correct wat to manage a app i guess thats y i got a -1, so when you do it like this please notice its not a right meathod to solve this problem even if this sactisfies your requirement. App shud not be launched again and again.

Comment: Yeah you really don't want to do this.  Quite a few things cause `onPause`; this will cause a really unpleasant user experience for anyone unfortunate enough to use an app that does this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

change this..

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent("com.exploreca.tourfinder.MainActivity");
startActivity(mainActivity);
```

to

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainActivity);
```

Comment: hi @Hariharan - I have added, but no difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    Handler handler;
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        SplashStart();
    }

    private void SplashStart() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
}

/* just add on resume method inside do not start your splace method in `onResume` method...*/
```